# I cannot figure out why I am getting this MySQL syntax error (PHP PDO) (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I am trying to do a simple insert into my MySQL database, but I get this syntax error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'Combined Authority - ICT Service Desk Technician (WYCA 53) ' at line 2
```

Why?

Query:

```
$conn->exec("INSERT INTO jobs (jobname, category, contract, link)
SELECT * FROM (" . $name[$i] . "," .  $category[$i] . "," . $contract[$i] 
. "," . $link[$i] . ") AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT link FROM jobs WHERE link = '" . " " . $link[$i] . ") LIMIT 1;");
```

$sql printed:

```
INSERT INTO jobs (jobname, category, contract, link) SELECT * FROM ( West
Yorkshire Combined Authority - ICT Service Desk Technician (WYCA 53)
Details ,' Other ',' Other
','https://bradford.engageats.co.uk/ViewVacancyV2.aspx?
enc=mEgrBL4XQK0+ld8aNkwYmF3VpPuSfX9mpz94c96U/BBgu1IZbwnQ0d+smFL6YrlPhdWkSGi559WmVou+xCXKsYHbHKP0EyHRCwf+vYTu8aYRJbtJgz78Wm2KQgu+LktushGT2Rg0PHjiRMA2Xyn4gw==') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT link FROM jobs WHERE link ='https://bradford.engageats.co.uk/ViewVacancyV2.aspx?enc=mEgrBL4XQK0+ld8aNkwYmF3VpPuSfX9mpz94c96U/BBgu1IZbwnQ0d+smFL6YrlPhdWkSGi559WmVou+xCXKsYHbHKP0EyHRCwf+vYTu8aYRJbtJgz78Wm2KQgu+LktushGT2Rg0PHjiRMA2Xyn4gw==') LIMIT 1;
```

Apologies for the poor formatting above. Please copy and paste it into a text editor to view it better.

EDIT:

Strangely, this query works with dummy values, but it's still not working for arrays

```
INSERT INTO jobs (jobname, category, contract, link)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Test', 'Test2',
'Test3','https://bradford.engageats.co.uk/ViewVacancyV2.aspx?
enc=mEgrBL4XQK0+ld8aNkwYmEUlxXraCLcDtY5P6rS92ks+pMDnlWa9QO6M/Df/HLticzgbgVWV
YayJj+zNDXalJnejkDY/4/gH0pIF9KyvMFXjn0u0quGSUzf4M/Gh0wF0MqIRgwLERFf+xXj6lw4s
tQ==') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT link FROM jobs WHERE link = 'https://bradford.engageats.co.uk/ViewVacancyV2.aspx?enc=mEgrBL4XQK0+ld8aNkwYmEUlxXraCLcDtY5P6rS92ks+pMDnlWa9QO6M/Df/HLticzgbgVWVYayJj+zNDXalJnejkDY/4/gH0pIF9KyvMFXjn0u0quGSUzf4M/Gh0wF0MqIRgwLERFf+xXj6lw4stQ=='
) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Share the query

Comment: You missing one `'` in yor syntax. And why do you add one space before the link value in the where part?

Comment: I think I may be able to fix this using the LIKE keyword, but how do I use it after the FROM keyword in this query?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Where am I missing a `'`?

Comment: In this area: `link = '" . " " . $link[$i] . ") LIMIT 1`  here is also the space added. IF i make a sql from it it will look like: `link = ' linkvalue) LIMIT 1` but it should `link = 'linkvalue' ) LIMIT 1`

Comment: Please show the generated query. Do `$conn->exec($sql="` and later `print $sql;` and show that here.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Thanks for pointing the error out, but I am still getting the same error. It is having problems with this: `'Combined Authority - ICT Service Desk Technician (WYCA 53) '`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Added the $sql in my edit

Comment: 1 moment. adding it now

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions The query still does not work even after all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can spot three different problems:

- First of all, you are inventing your own SQL syntax and the server is not amused. You cannot `SELECT * FROM (anything you want)`. You can only select from tables, views or subqueries.
- Secondly, when you type e.g. `foo` in SQL the database engine needs a way to figure out if you mean a table or column or you mean literal word. The method used is *single quotes*:

  ```
  SELECT foo AS this_is_a_column, 'foo' AS this_is_a_value
  FROM bar
  ```

  You can find more details at [What is the difference between an identifier and a literal?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-an-identifier-and-a-literal)
- Last but not least, your overall use of the PDO extension is wrong. PDO provides a way to separate code and data but you are not using it. Rather than this:

  ```
  $conn->exec("SELECT link FROM jobs WHERE link = '" . " " . $link[$i] . ") LIMIT 1;");
  ```

  ... you should be doing something like this:

  ```
  $stmt = $conn->prepared("SELECT link FROM jobs WHERE link=? LIMIT 1"); 
  $stmt->execute($stmt, array($link[$i]));
  ```

Comment: When I use the query without the arrays it works as expected. :) (If I use it with dummy values) My suspicion is that the syntax within the array elements is not written correctly. Also, thanks for the tip

Comment: See my edit. I did not invent my own syntax. It works just fine when I do it in that way, but not with arrays.

Comment: Well, `SELECT * FROM ( West
Yorkshire Combined Authority - ICT Service Desk Technician ...)` is definitively non-standard :)

Comment: So why do you think it works with my new edited query and not the original one?

Comment: Because the second query fixes the syntax and adds the missing `SELECT`?

Comment: If it doesn't work there must be something wrong. Try fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

try this select query and do same with other variables :

```
SELECT * FROM ("'".$name[$i]."','".$category[$i]."', '".$contract[$i] ."', '". $link[$i] ."'") AS tmp
```

Comment: @e4c5 Tell me why my question is bad

Comment: simple syntax error questions are off topic.And you are using string concat which is absurd. specially when you use PDO

Comment: @e4c5 Tell me why it's absurd. You do not contribute if you just say it's absurd

Answer (score 0):

Use Quotes for string litterals 
backticks for columns and tables names.

For more reference Check: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php